clmm function gives me an error "Error in x$code == 0L || action == "silent" : Error 'length = 2' in coercion to 'logical(1)'"
The following commands regarding the two types of models are executed in R
model_4_clmm <- clmm(v27_3 ~ SEX_2 + AGE + PARTLIV_2 + EDULEVEL_2 + WORK_2 + ISCO08_2 + PARTY_LR_2 + v4_3 + gdp_per_capita.x + (1 | country), data = ISSP2020)
model_5_clmm <- clmm(v27_3 ~ SEX_2 + AGE + PARTLIV_2 + EDULEVEL_2 + WORK_2 + ISCO08_2 + PARTY_LR_2 + v4_3 + gdp_per_capita.x + greentax_gdp_ratio.x + (1 | country), data = ISSP2020)
With model_4_clmm, the following error occurs, but with model_5_clmm, no error occurs and it is executed successfully.
Error in x$code == 0L || action == "silent" : 
  'length = 2' in coercion to 'logical(1)'

How to solve this? I want to make model_4_clmm run.
In addition, the model for the following test ran without problems.
model_test <- clmm(v27_3 ~ SEX_2 + AGE + PARTLIV_2 + EDULEVEL_2 + WORK_2 + ISCO08_2 + PARTY_LR_2 + v4_3 + greentax_gdp_ratio.x + (1 | country), data = ISSP2020)

Read this to learn how to post a good question.

Thank you for sharing. this is my first question, so let me edit.
